# Go AST / Types - how to tell an error?

Tags: go, types, abstract-syntax-tree

Is there a better way of doing this? I need to know if the type of v is the built-in "error" type. I feel like there should be a neater way of doing this:

```
import (
    "go/ast"
    "go/types"
)

func IsError(v ast.Expr, info types.Info) bool {
    t := info.Types[v]
    return t.Type.String() == "error" &&
        t.Type.Underlying().String() == "interface{Error() string}"
}
```

Comment: Please add a runnable link. For example using https://github.com/plutov/playgo

Comment: Here's a runnable example: https://play.golang.org/p/MrhlFdBN3w

Comment: I think this one is enough:

  return info.Types[v].Type.String() == "error"

Answer (score 1):

[Type assertion](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#interface_conversions) is the idiomatic way of checking the type of a variable.

Given you're handling an AST expression, I'd try to check if the underlying type is an interface and if the `Error()` method is implemented:

```
isError := func(v ast.Expr, info *types.Info) bool {
    if intf, ok := info.TypeOf(v).Underlying().(*types.Interface); ok {
        return intf.NumMethods() == 1 && intf.Method(0).FullName() == "(error).Error"
    }
    return false
}
```

Comment: In regular code, yes. But I'm scanning the AST of a source file, so I have an ast.Expr as input.

Answer (score 0):

I think I prefer this solution:

https://play.golang.org/p/MA7F4Zpwqt

```
isError := func(v ast.Expr, info *types.Info) bool {
    if n, ok := info.TypeOf(v).(*types.Named); ok {
        o := n.Obj()
        return o != nil && o.Pkg() == nil && o.Name() == "error"
    }
    return false
}
```